# Final Cut output to FFmpeg workflow

Tags: ffmpeg, final-cut-pro-x

If I use Apple Compressor, I could just 'Send to Compressor', without first exporting a ProRes master.

However, I would like to use FFmpeg/x264 for better quality (at low bitrate).

Do I have to export the master first? It is 150 GB/hour and exceeds my remaining disk space. Or is there a 'streaming workflow'?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and add your own share destination setting into FCPX.
Click on the Share button in FCPX, then in the opened share window click on 'Add Destination'. In the right half of the window, you see all the possible options. Click on 'Compressor Settings' and another window will open. You might find and can finetune one of these settings.